# How to make that when hovering the background color becomes visible and a button with text appears?

Tags: html, css

I have a block in which the picture is located. It is necessary that when you hover, a translucent red background and text with a button appear, but they are already completely transparent. I will be very grateful for the decision!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLx2H.jpg

```css
 .LatestWorks_imagesgrid{
        width: 1140px;
        height: 1020px;
        display: grid;
    justify-items:center;
    align-items:center;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
    }

.imagegridboss{
  height:320px;
  width:360px;
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2KX3.jpg);

}

.imagegridboss h1{
  opacity:0;
}

.imagegrid_child{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
            <div class="LatestWorks_imagesgrid">

        <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

         <div class="imagegridboss">
                <h1>computer</h1>
                <div class="imagegrid">
                    <div class="imagegrid_child">
                        <span>View</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you share a live link or your codes?

Comment: We don't/can't debug images. Post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing my CSS (under /* New Code */) on the HTML structure you have in place, although there are changes I would make to make this even simpler. Basically you want to use a `:hover` state, then a few tricks to get everything centered and z-indexed properly:

```css
.LatestWorks_imagesgrid {
  width: 1140px;
  height: 1020px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.imagegridboss {
  height: 320px;
  width: 360px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2KX3.jpg);
}

.imagegridboss h1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.imagegrid_child {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* New code */
.imagegridboss {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.imagegridboss:hover h1,
.imagegridboss:hover .imagegrid_child {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

.imagegridboss > * {
  position: absolute;
}

.imagegridboss:hover::after {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="LatestWorks_imagesgrid">

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imagegridboss">
    <h1>computer</h1>
    <div class="imagegrid">
      <div class="imagegrid_child">
        <span>View</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is how it should be. Thank you so much for the decision!